# Use associative array to merge two objects based on ID

Tags: php, twitter

So I have the following method `$data = Twitter::get_profile_tweets()` which outputs the following response:

```
object(stdClass)#1597 (3) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#1612 (4) {
      ["text"]=>
      string(231) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
      ["id"]=>
      string(19) "1487953501825163264"
      ["author_id"]=>
      string(19) "1487104761291849728"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#1586 (5) {
      ["attachments"]=>
      object(stdClass)#1606 (1) {
        ["media_keys"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(22) "16_1487594952561467393"
        }
      }
      ["text"]=>
      string(56) "Telling myself how I really feel"
      ["id"]=>
      string(19) "1487594959125549059"
      ["author_id"]=>
      string(19) "1487104761291849728"
    }
  }
  ["includes"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1604 (2) {
    ["users"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      object(stdClass)#1591 (9) {
        ["profile_image_url"]=>
        string(78) "https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_normal.png"
        ["id"]=>
        string(19) "1487104761291849728"
        ["name"]=>
        string(14) "FHTechServices"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The API response makes no sense, but I guess you have to match the data tweets return to the corresponding user.

---

**Here is what I'm attempting to do**:

Let's say this would be the ideal return:

```
object(stdClass)#1597 (3) {
  array(2) {
    [0] => {
        [0] => {
            object(stdClass)#1612 (4) {
              ["text"]=>
              string(231) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
              ["id"]=>
              string(19) "1487953501825163264"
              ["author_id"]=>
              string(19) "1487104761291849728"
            }
        [1] => 
            object(stdClass)#1591 (9) {
              ["profile_image_url"]=>
              string(78) "https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_normal.png"
              ["id"]=>
              string(19) "1487104761291849728"
              ["name"]=>
              string(14) "FHTechServices"
            }
        }
    }
    [1] => {
        [0] => {
            object(stdClass)#1612 (4) {
              ["text"]=>
              string(231) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
              ["id"]=>
              string(19) "1487953501825163264"
              ["author_id"]=>
              string(19) "1487104761291849728"
            }
        }
        [1] => {
            object(stdClass)#1591 (9) {
              ["profile_image_url"]=>
              string(78) "https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_normal.png"
              ["id"]=>
              string(19) "1487104761291849728"
              ["name"]=>
              string(14) "FHTechServices"
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

We looked at `["data"]` in the first index and grabbed the Author ID and then looked at the ID inside `["includes"]["users"]` and if it matches, merge its own array of object.

**Unsure about the below, since there might be key collisions**:

What if we can just merge it all into one single array or object, so then I don't have to do [0] for the tweet keys and [1] for the user keys, I can just loop and grab the keys such as:

```
[0] => {
    [0] => {
        object(stdClass)#1612 (4) {
          ["text"]=>
          string(231) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
          ["id"]=>
          string(19) "1487953501825163264"
          ["author_id"]=>
          string(19) "1487104761291849728"
          ["profile_image_url"]=>
          string(78) "https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_normal.png"
          ["id"]=>
          string(19) "1487104761291849728"
          ["name"]=>
          string(14) "FHTechServices"
        }
    }
}
```

This sounds extremely confusing, so all help will be really appreciated!

Comment: You cannot possibly have multiple `id` keys in the same level -- later occurring `id` values will overwrite earlier stored `id` values.  Your requested output is impossible.  Please have a re-think and [edit] your question to be something that can be answered.  We would also like to see your attempt to group and merge these data points.  Stack Overflow already has loads of PHP grouping pages for you to peruse.

Comment: @mickmackusa I guess it is possible, thanks for your input tho!

Comment: No.  It's impossible.  Your accepted answer did not give you what you asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requested output contains 2 ID fields and really just needs ID and author_id.

On the combined object we need to map the ID field on the user to the author ID field on the tweet!

So first we make a lookup table (array) with our users that lets us map the author_id on a tweet to the id field on the user.

Then when we loop through our tweets we can add the user details as needed.

```
<?php

$twitter_data = (object) [
    'data' => [
        (object) [
            'text' => "Follow DataTongue on twitter",
            'id' => "1487953501825163264",
            'author_id' => "14871047612917656543",
        ],

        (object) [
            'text' => "My name is Keith Ismael",
            'id' => "1487953501825112346",
            'author_id' => "14871047612918412345",
        ],

        (object) [
            'text' => "My name is Paul Malvino",
            'id' => "1487953501825198765",
            'author_id' => "14871047612918469875",
        ],
    ],

    'includes' => (object) [
        'users' => [
            (object) [
                'profile_image_url' => "https://example.com",
                'id' => "14871047612918469875",
                'name' => "Paul Malvino",
            ],
            (object) [
                'profile_image_url' => "https://example.com",
                'id' => "14871047612918412345",
                'name' => "Keith Ismael",
            ],
            (object) [
                'profile_image_url' => "https://example.com",
                'id' => "14871047612917656543",
                'name' => "Sally Pemdas",
            ],
        ],
    ]   
];

function mergeTweetsWithUsers ($merge_me) {
    $users_lookup = [];
    $combined_output = [];
    
    foreach ($merge_me->includes->users as $key => $user) {
        $users_lookup[$user->id] = $user;
    }

    foreach ($merge_me->data as $tweet) {
        $merged_tweet = $tweet;
        $merged_tweet->author_name = $users_lookup[$tweet->author_id]->name;
        $merged_tweet->author_profile_image_url = $users_lookup[$tweet->author_id]->profile_image_url;

        $combined_output[] = $merged_tweet;
    }

    return $combined_output;
}

mergeTweetsWithUsers($twitter_data);

/*
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
    ["text"]=>
    string(28) "Follow DataTongue on twitter"
    ["id"]=>
    string(19) "1487953501825163264"
    ["author_id"]=>
    string(20) "14871047612917656543"
    ["author_name"]=>
    string(12) "Sally Pemdas"
    ["author_profile_image_url"]=>
    string(19) "https://example.com"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (5) {
    ["text"]=>
    string(23) "My name is Keith Ismael"
    ["id"]=>
    string(19) "1487953501825112346"
    ["author_id"]=>
    string(20) "14871047612918412345"
    ["author_name"]=>
    string(12) "Keith Ismael"
    ["author_profile_image_url"]=>
    string(19) "https://example.com"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (5) {
    ["text"]=>
    string(23) "My name is Paul Malvino"
    ["id"]=>
    string(19) "1487953501825198765"
    ["author_id"]=>
    string(20) "14871047612918469875"
    ["author_name"]=>
    string(12) "Paul Malvino"
    ["author_profile_image_url"]=>
    string(19) "https://example.com"
  }
}

*/
```